# Can you solve the connecting wall?

Tags: wordplay, connect-wall

This puzzle is based on the "connecting wall" from the British tv show "Only Connect". The goal is to group the 16 words into 4 groups of 4 words that all share a property. Here are the words:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MIX | LASER | RACECAR | EMPTY |
| SONAR | SCUBA | NOON | VIM |
| MOSSY | KAYAK | LIVID | BOOST |
| CIVIL | ROTATOR | CAPTCHA | BIOPSY |

What are the four groups of words?
What is the connection between the words in each group?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Group 1:

> ACRONYM words, containing SONAR, LASER, CAPTCHA, SCUBA.

Group 2:

> ROMAN NUMERAL words, containing CIVIL, MIX, LIVID, VIM.

Group 3:

> PALINDROMIC words, containing NOON, RACECAR, KAYAK, ROTATOR.

Group 4:

> ALPHABETICAL ORDER words, containing MOSSY, EMPTY, BOOST, BIOPSY.

Comment: Just ahead of me, the last group is rot13(jbeqf gung ner va nycunorgvpny beqre)

Comment: Your groupings are correct.

Comment: @user197974 Finished it off. Thanks to hexomino for the Group 4 connection!

Comment: Happy 1,000th answer!